# How to get the position of screen window of browser when scroll down jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is script will query data from Database when user scroll to bottom of website
But I want query data before the arrow bar equal to bottom of browser.
I want to query data or load ajax when user scroll till 2/3 or near arrive the bottom of browser not till bottom of browser

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    document.addEventListener("scroll", function() { // or window.addEventListener("scroll"....

        var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if (st > lastScrollTop) {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {

                $.ajax({
                    url:'products/scroll',
                    method:'get',
                    dataType:'html',
                    data:{},
                    success : function (data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $(data).appendTo('.load-more-block')
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    }, false);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. If you want the "infinite scroll" effect, you'll have to reset the `triggerFlag`, as well as re-update `docHeight` and `triggerHeight` values to whatever the new document height is whenever your DOM updates with the new values from the ajax request.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var triggerHeight = docHeight*0.6667;
  
  $("#docHeight").text(docHeight); //Ignore
  $("#triggerHeight").text(triggerHeight); //Ignore
  
  
  var triggerFlag = false;
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#height").text($(this).scrollTop()); //Ignore
    if (!triggerFlag && $(this).scrollTop() > triggerHeight){
      //Execute code here
      triggerFlag = true;
      $("#status").text("Executed at " + new Date());
      
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html{
  height: 6000px;
}

p{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Current Height: <span id='height'>0</span><br>
    Window Height: <span id='docHeight'>0</span><br>
    Trigger Height: <span id='triggerHeight'>0</span><br>
    Status: <span id='status'>false</span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why we know to use docHeight*0.6667;? do we can use docHeight*0.1667; or another value?